# Is the "C" wire here tied to ground?

Tags: thermostat, heating, thermostat-c-wire

Looking at this diagram, it looks like the "C" wire for a thermostat, marked as "COM" on some intermediate component my garage heater, is actually also tied to the ground of the equipment? Is that correct?

[image: garage heater wiring diagram]

If so, would it be OK/safe to use one of the other ground connections as a place to connect my thermostat "C" wire? The "COM" terminal elsewhere is just a spade terminal already connected to other things, so I don't see a good way to connect anything else until it reaches the ground, unless I were to cut one of those other wires and use a screw nut or something?

This is for a gas heater in my garage.

I attempted to use a multimeter in continuity mode and it beeped when I touched ground and the 24V terminals of the transformer, but I'm not 100% sure I am using it right, especially since it beeped for *both* of the terminals.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok, but not ideal, to connect your thermostat C wire to any convenient place that is attached to ground if the 24V Common side is also attached that way, so long as the transformer is part of the heater and you make the connection within the heater enclosure.

The reason to keep it within the enclosure is to make *reasonably* sure you will have good continuity, and to make it *reasonably* easy to debug if you don't.  It may be tempting, for example, to attach the thermostat C terminal to a nearby metal junction box that is grounded, providing continuity to the transformer through the house grounding system, and it may work.  But in the long run, it may stop working and you'll have an awful time figuring out why.

It's really not that hard to cut a wire and connect the two loose ends to each other and to your new thermostat wire!

Comment: My question was about attaching a spare wire in the thermostat wire to the ground screw within the heater's electonics box. (A green screw that is one of the screws mounting the transformer to the enclosure)

Comment: Yes that ought to work, as your 24V Common is also (according to the diagram) connected that way and your testing confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, COM stands for “common” or  ground. The upside-down fork symbol shown connected indicates ground. So yes, you can connect the wire to any screw connected to the metal frame of the heater.

The reason you got continuity on both terminals of the transformer is that the transformer winding looks like a short circuit for DC voltage (used by your continuity tester).